# How should the code-signing be set up for Push Notification Services?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-push-notifications

Push was working fine in dev. Then I released to iTunes and changed my server to use the Apple production address and production certificate. Now the released version doesn't register on the PNS, and I think it might be because of how my code-signing was set up. Can anyone confirm this please?

[image: Target settings]

[image: Project settings]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps someone one day.
Project Code -signing - Release - Distribution with company handler
        Provisioning Profile - Release - Distribution provisioning profile.
Target Code - signing - Release - Distribution with company handler
        Provisioning Profile - Release - Distribution provisioning profile.

Here are some pics as well in case this is not clear.

**Also I noticed afterward that you can test the Production Push Notifications with Apples Testflight if you have configured your PNS for production**

[image: Project Settings]

[image: Target Settings]